# How to get a TurnBasedMatch from a TurnbasedMatchBuffer

Tags: android, google-play-games

```
        TurnBasedMatchBuffer buff = result.getMatches().getMyTurnMatches();

    m_iMyTurnMatches = buff.getCount();
    if (m_iMyTurnMatches > 0){
        mMatch = buff.get(0);
    }
    buff.close();
```

The code above is supposed to fill mMatch with a TurnBasedMatch, yet when I try to get the status of mMatch, I get a crash.

How can I get mMatch in a usable form?

Comment: What's the crash?  Can you post the log?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get the solution?